# how to check if all the elements in the list is in another list but using index

Tags: python

if I have a such list `['KS', '0C', '8C', '3S']`, how do I check if all the `[1]` index in each element is in this list: `['C', 'S']`?

Comment: `all(e[1] in ['C', 'S'] for e in ['KS', '0C', '8C', '3S'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax almost follows your question, using `all` method

```
res = all(elt[1] in ['C', 'S'] for elt in ['KS', '0C', '8C', '3S'])
```